# PyQT center toolbar buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

By default the toolbar buttons in PyQT are aligned to the left, is it possible to make them centered so that they slide along when resizing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am not sure I understand correctly, but if you are looking for a way to center buttons on toolbar *with respect to* `QMainWindow`, then yes there is a (hackish) way. You just need to put a widget that acts like a 'spacer'. That is basically a `QWidget` with `expanding` size policy.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = QtGui.QMainWindow()
toolbar = QtGui.QToolBar()

# spacer widget for left
left_spacer = QtGui.QWidget()
left_spacer.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
# spacer widget for right
# you can't add the same widget to both left and right. you need two different widgets.
right_spacer = QtGui.QWidget()
right_spacer.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

# here goes the left one
toolbar.addWidget(left_spacer)
# some dummy actions
toolbar.addAction('one')
toolbar.addAction('two')
toolbar.addAction('three')
# and the right one
toolbar.addWidget(right_spacer)

main.addToolBar(toolbar)
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which gives you this:

[image]